# How to validate a list of ranges amongst each other?

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

Having such an class:

```
public class MyRange
{
    public int From {get; set;}
    public int To {get; set;}

    public MyRange(int from, int to)
    {
        From = from;
        To = to;
    }
}
```

And having a `List<MyRange>` with the following values:

```
var list = new List<MyRange>();
list.Add(new MyRange(1, 1000));
list.Add(new MyRange(1001, 2000));
list.Add(new MyRange(50, 1500));
list.Add(new MyRange(1900, 2900));
```

Is it possible to have a `FluentValidation` rule that checks that the above ranges do not overlap? (Gaps between ranges are valid)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by ordering ranges on the `From` property, and then checking that the `To` property of the prior element is below the `From` property of the current element:

```
var ordered = list.OrderBy(r => r.From).ToList();
var isValid = ordered
    .Zip(ordered.Skip(1), (a, b) => new {Prior = a, Current = b})
    .All(p => p.Prior.To <= p.Current.From);
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ can help you here:

```
bool overlaps = list.Any(r => list
                           .Except(new[] { r })
                           .Any(r2 => r.From >= r2.From && r.To <= r2.To)
                        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Using nested `.Any` :

```
list.Any(x => list.Any(y => x.From < y.From && x.To > y.From || x.From < y.From && x.To > y.From))
```

This iterates the list as two `foreach`instructions one with `x` variable and one with `y` variable and checks for overlapping between each of these variables using the condition which would have been used in the two `foreach` instructions:

```
x.From < y.From && x.To > y.From || x.From < y.From && x.To > y.From
```

The advantage is that this is more clear than iterating both lists and applying the condition, and it can be written into a single line without any effort.